# Getopt::Std in Perl with repeated arguments

Tags: linux, perl

Below is a snippet of my code which calls getopts

```
getopts("sdlaLRGr:g:c:t:", \%options);
```

Now, when I run below command its not throwing an error.

```
perl rolemanage.pl -add -r ROLE_NET_USER -c /bin/date -t rtp99
```

Here command args "-add", only -a is expected but as "d" is also part of getopts, getopts is not throwing any error instead executing the command successfully.

Could any one explain the reason for this. Is there any solution to throw an error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getopt::Std supports **single character switches with clustering**.  The switch(es) -add is the same as passing the 3 switches -a -d -d.

The solution you're looking for is to use Getopt::Long instead of Getopt::Std.